# Executing a .cfm script with php

Tags: php, curl, coldfusion, https

I'm using the following code to remotely execute a script:

```
$url = 'https://x.x.com/update_something.cfm?something_id=' . $id;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

The script, however, it's not being executed (when I visit the url above from the browser, I can see the updated results, when doing it from the php script above nothing happens. PHP is not giving me any errors though, it just finishes the execution. What am I missing?

Comment: Try turning the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option on to get some debugging info, and also check the return value of `curl_error()` to be sure. If nothing obvious is wrong with the request, try modifying the request headers to resemble your browser's request more closely, sometimes scripts whine about things like `User-Agent` and `Referer` headers.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($response)` after the exec call. if it comes out boolean false, then something didn't work right with the curl call. You can get the error text with `echo curl_error($ch)`

Comment: Thanks, I ran it and got 'SSL connection timeout', not sure how to solve this, I tried CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to a high number but it's not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);` made it work! :)

Comment: Please note that [disabling VERIFYPEER or VERIFYHOST makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13742121/372643).